# Why does this function console.log 20 times instead of once?

Tags: javascript, ajax, heroku

In application.js, I have all the 'topics' compiling on the page from an ajax call, and then when one is clicked, all the information appears on the screen. Everything works great in development, but in production I get a 500 server error.

In trying to debug this, I noticed that the console is logging 20 times with the .onclick call. Why is this happening, and does it have any reason why it is returning a 500 error in production (heroku)?

I put ** ** around the 3 console.logs where this is happening.

```
if(window.location.pathname === "/topics")  {
    $('.actions').click(function(e) {
        console.log("submit");
    })

    $.ajax({
            url: '/topics',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result)   {
                console.log(result);
                for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)  {
                    var title = result[i].title;
                    var level = result[i].level;
                    var id = result[i].id;
                    var favlink = '/topics/' + id + '/favorite';    
                    var link = '/topics/' + id;
                    var topicInfo = {title: title, link: link};
                    var template = compiledTopics(topicInfo);
                    $('.topic-wrapper').append(template);



                $('.listing-topics, .favorite-topic-title').click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if( $(this).hasClass("favorite-topic-title"))   {
                            var heartClass = "favorited_heart_icon"

                        }
                        else if( $(this).hasClass("listing-topics"))    {
                            var heartClass = "unfavorited_heart_icon";
                            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');

                        }
                        **console.log(this);**
                        $.ajax({
                            url: this,
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: 'GET',
                            success: function(result)   {


                                var id = result.id;
                                var title = result.title;
                                var body = result.body;
                                var level = result.level
                                **console.log(level);**

                                //SHOW TOPIC and FAVTOPIC AS POPUP WHEN CLICKED

                                //Add proper favorite icon.
                                var favlink = '/topics/' + id + '/favorite';    
                                **console.log(heartClass);**
                                var topicInfo = {title: title, body: body, heartClass: heartClass};
                                var template = compiled(topicInfo);



                                $('.topic-wrapper').append(template);

                                //CLOSE TOPIC WHEN CLICKING THE GREY SURROUNDING BOX - topicClose
                                $('.topicClose').click(function(e)  {
                                    $('.topicClose').css("display", "none");
                                    $('.show_topic').css("display", "none");
                                })

                                //FAVORITE TOPIC
                                //ADD TO FAV TOPICS LIST

                                $(".unfavorited_heart_icon, .favorited_heart_icon").click(function(e)   {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    //onclick - change colors of heart

                                    if ( $(this).hasClass("favorited_heart_icon"))  {
                                        $(this).removeClass("favorited_heart_icon");
                                        $(this).addClass("unfavorited_heart_icon");
                                        urlEnd = '/unfavorite';
                                    }
                                    else if ( $(this). hasClass("unfavorited_heart_icon"))  {
                                        $(this).removeClass("unfavorited_heart_icon");
                                        $(this).addClass("favorited_heart_icon");
                                        urlEnd = '/favorite';
                                    }
                                    // console.log('/topics/favorite/' + id);
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: '/topics/' + id + urlEnd,  
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        success: function(result)   {
                                            location.reload();
                                        }
                                    })

                                });



                            },
                            error: function(err)    {
                                console.log(err);
                            }


                        })
                    });


            };

        },
        error: function(err)    {

        }
    });
```

at the bottom of same js file:

```
var listingSource = $("#listingTopics").html();
var compiledTopics = Handlebars.compile(listingSource);
```

topics handlebar template:

```
<script id="listingTopics">
  <div>
    <a href={{link}} class="listing-topics">{{title}}</a>   
  </div>
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT**

I've also tried:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/topics',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(result)   {
                    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)  {
                        var title = result[i].title;
                        var level = result[i].level;
                        var id = result[i].id;
                        var favlink = '/topics/' + id + '/favorite';    
                        var link = '/topics/' + id;
                        var topicInfo = {title: title, link: link};
                        var template = compiledTopics(topicInfo);
                        $('.topic-wrapper').append(template).click(function(e)  {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            console.log($(this))
                        });
                };
            },
```

Comment: You’re binding 20 event listeners in total within your loop. All 20 are called on click.

Comment: @user2267175 I added one ebfore the ajax call, and it only ran once. It seems as if it is something happening inside the call

Comment: I'm guessing that `results` is roughly 20 items. When you're creating your `click` event handler within your for loop, your binding it to a classes `.listing-topics, .favorite-topic-title`. When you click on the element it goes ahead and fires the click events (20 times since you have 20 items in you results array). I suspect this is what is happening but need to see it to verify. Do you have a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Xufox can you explain a little more? I'm new to ajax -- where do you see it binding 20 times?

Comment: @gwalshington: mwilson explained it pretty well. This has nothing to do with AJAX. `for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){`…`$('.listing-topics, .favorite-topic-title').click(function(e){`…`});`…`}` is binding a new click listener `result.length` times.

Comment: @Xufox I understand the logic, but not how to fix it. Do I need to take the .click event outside of the original ajax call? How do I specify that I only want the click even to be associated with the topic that is clicked? also -- is the issue coming from the fact that it's in another ajax call, or that i'm calling .click on a generic class, and not a specific instance? still slightly confused how to solve. thanks!!

Comment: @gwalshington It depends on what your HTML looks like and where the classes `listing-topics` and `favorite-topic-title` are. Effectively, you need to pick only one set of those elements for each iteration and bind the listener there. Currently, you’re binding a listener to all sets, each time. As I said before, the AJAX calls are not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that `results` is roughly 20 items. When you're creating your `click` event handler within your for loop, your binding it to a classes `.listing-topics, .favorite-topic-title`. When you click on the element it goes ahead and fires the click events (20 times since you have 20 items in you results array). I suspect this is what is happening but need to see it to verify. Do you have a JSFiddle?

To fix this, change up the way you're binding your event handler. You need to scope it to a specific instance of a class or element in order for the events to fire individually instead of all at once.

**SAMPLE SCENARIO**

```
var results = ["1", "2", "3"];


//How you're currently doing it
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    $('#container').append($('<div />', {text: results[i], class:'test-class'}));
  $('.test-class').click(function () {
  console.log($(this).text());
  });
}

//Solution
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    $('#container').append($('<div />', {text: results[i], class:'test-class'}).click(function () {
  console.log($(this).text());
  }));
}
```

I have created a simple reproduction of this scenario (aligning with yours) to help better explain what's happening. Basically, instaed of binding all your events within one go (by class), bind it to the element as you're creating it.

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/ncrxekmq/

**UPDATED CODE**

```
if(window.location.pathname === "/topics")  {
    $('.actions').click(function(e) {
        console.log("submit");
    })

    $.ajax({
            url: '/topics',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result)   {
                console.log(result);
                for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)  {
                    var title = result[i].title;
                    var level = result[i].level;
                    var id = result[i].id;
                    var favlink = '/topics/' + id + '/favorite';    
                    var link = '/topics/' + id;
                    var topicInfo = {title: title, link: link};
                    var template = compiledTopics(topicInfo);
                    $('.topic-wrapper').append(template);


                //use $.each(index, item) to loop through all of your elements and bind the click event individually instead of in one go.
                $('.listing-topics, .favorite-topic-title').each(function (index, item) {
                    $(item).click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if( $(this).hasClass("favorite-topic-title"))   {
                            var heartClass = "favorited_heart_icon"

                        }
                        else if( $(this).hasClass("listing-topics"))    {
                            var heartClass = "unfavorited_heart_icon";
                            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');

                        }
                        **console.log(this);**
                        $.ajax({
                            url: this,
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: 'GET',
                            success: function(result)   {


                                var id = result.id;
                                var title = result.title;
                                var body = result.body;
                                var level = result.level
                                **console.log(level);**

                                //SHOW TOPIC and FAVTOPIC AS POPUP WHEN CLICKED

                                //Add proper favorite icon.
                                var favlink = '/topics/' + id + '/favorite';    
                                **console.log(heartClass);**
                                var topicInfo = {title: title, body: body, heartClass: heartClass};
                                var template = compiled(topicInfo);



                                $('.topic-wrapper').append(template);

                                //CLOSE TOPIC WHEN CLICKING THE GREY SURROUNDING BOX - topicClose
                                $('.topicClose').click(function(e)  {
                                    $('.topicClose').css("display", "none");
                                    $('.show_topic').css("display", "none");
                                })

                                //FAVORITE TOPIC
                                //ADD TO FAV TOPICS LIST

                                $(".unfavorited_heart_icon, .favorited_heart_icon").click(function(e)   {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    //onclick - change colors of heart

                                    if ( $(this).hasClass("favorited_heart_icon"))  {
                                        $(this).removeClass("favorited_heart_icon");
                                        $(this).addClass("unfavorited_heart_icon");
                                        urlEnd = '/unfavorite';
                                    }
                                    else if ( $(this). hasClass("unfavorited_heart_icon"))  {
                                        $(this).removeClass("unfavorited_heart_icon");
                                        $(this).addClass("favorited_heart_icon");
                                        urlEnd = '/favorite';
                                    }
                                    // console.log('/topics/favorite/' + id);
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: '/topics/' + id + urlEnd,  
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        success: function(result)   {
                                            location.reload();
                                        }
                                    })

                                });



                            },
                            error: function(err)    {
                                console.log(err);
                            }


                        })
                    });
                });

            };

        },
        error: function(err)    {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I agree with this logic, but How would I be able to uniquely identify the specific instance that I am clicking on if not through `this`, and not have it be associate with the total number of topics instances? thanks!

Comment: JSFiddle added. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: My theory is that as a test, move your event binding outside of your for loop in the ajax call. Create a second iterator to bind the click events by using `$.each` (under the assumption your element count to results count it the same) it will match up and you should get the individual event bindings.

Comment: I have added what you said above, and unfortunately its sill duplicating several times. I will add the exact code above so you can see.

Comment: I've updated your code with what I think should work. Since I don't have a live example of your code, it may be off (slightly) but this should at least show you what solves the problem. If you can reproduce you problem in a JSFiddle, it would be easiest to give you a good working example there. See my updated answer for the new code.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of the problems you are having with the assignment of multiple event listeners can be solved by taking those listeners out of the loops and defining them using the delegate strategy.

I would try something conceptually something similar to:

```
function getTopicJSON_Success(result){
    console.log(result);

    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)  {
        var title = result[i].title;
        var level = result[i].level;
        var id = result[i].id;
        var favlink = '/topics/' + id + '/favorite';    
        var link = '/topics/' + id;
        var topicInfo = { title: title, link: link };
        var template = compiledTopics(topicInfo);
        $('.topic-wrapper').append(template);
    }
}

function getJSON_Error(err){
    console.log(err);
}

if(window.location.pathname === "/topics")  {

    $('.actions').click(function(e) {
        console.log("submit");
    });

    $('.topic-wrapper').on("click", '.listing-topics, .favorite-topic-title', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // =========================
        // Note at this point "this" is the element that was clicked.
        // in the ajax requrest below we will want to use $this.attr("href").
        // =========================
        console.log(this);
        // =========================

        var $this = $(this);
        var heartClass;

        if( $this.hasClass("favorite-topic-title") ) {
            heartClass = "favorited_heart_icon"
        } else if( $this.hasClass("listing-topics") ) {
            heartClass = "unfavorited_heart_icon";
            $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
        }

        // =========================
        // Note: could be "null".
        // Did you want one or the other specifically and not the posibility of null?
        // =========================
        console.log(heartClass);
        // =========================

        var getListJSON_Success = function(result){
            var id = result.id;
            var title = result.title;
            var body = result.body;
            var level = result.level

            console.log(level);

            //SHOW TOPIC and FAVTOPIC AS POPUP WHEN CLICKED

            //Add proper favorite icon.
            var favlink = '/topics/' + id + '/favorite';    
            var topicInfo = {title: title, body: body, heartClass: heartClass};
            var template = compiled(topicInfo);

            $('.topic-wrapper').append(template);

            //CLOSE TOPIC WHEN CLICKING THE GREY SURROUNDING BOX - topicClose
            $('.topicClose').click(function(e)  {
                $('.topicClose').css("display", "none");
                $('.show_topic').css("display", "none");
            });

            //FAVORITE TOPIC
            //ADD TO FAV TOPICS LIST
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: $this.attr("href"),
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET',
            success: getListJSON_Success,
            error: getJSON_Error
        })
    });

    $('.topic-wrapper').on("click", ".unfavorited_heart_icon, .favorited_heart_icon", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);
        var urlEnd;

        if ( $this.hasClass("favorited_heart_icon") ) {
            $this.removeClass("favorited_heart_icon");
            $this.addClass("unfavorited_heart_icon");
            urlEnd = '/unfavorite';
        } else if ( $this. hasClass("unfavorited_heart_icon") ) {
            $this.removeClass("unfavorited_heart_icon");
            $this.addClass("favorited_heart_icon");
            urlEnd = '/favorite';
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/topics/' + $this.attr("id") + urlEnd,  
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result) { location.reload(); },
            error: getJSON_Error
        });

    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '/topics',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: getTopicJSON_Success,
        error: getJSON_Error
    });
}
```